# Deploy fail when try to send iOS app to real iPhone 5S device

Tags: xcode

Today, I try to deploy my iOS app on my iPhone 5S device.

It works in the last week, but I try it now and I got the following error:

Unable to launch: Error -12

If I try to deploy to iOS Simulator, it works perfectly. But I need to use the camera now and because of that, I need to deploy it to a real device.

I use my personal account(free Apple Id), I'm not enrolled in the Apple Developer Program.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out the problem.

I forget to turn on the Wifi on my iPhone 5S.

The message error could be more clear.